# How to make POST request in Restler Client?

Tags: php, web-services, rest, post, restler

I'm using [Restler 3](https://github.com/Luracast/Restler) library and I want to make a post request from php . 
I tried this way :

**POSTing JSON Data With PHP cURL**

```
$data=array('name'=>'ddddd','email'=>'sdfsdf@sdgdsg');                                                                   
$data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                   

$ch = curl_init('http://192.168.0.101/Restler-3rc3-Stable/public/examples/_007_crud/Authors');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

and also this way **without cURL**:

```
//Pick your own method.by uncommenting one of the VERBS
//$method='GET';
$method='POST';
//$method='PUT';
//$method='DELETE';


$id=21;
$response_header=array();

//Point this URL to your own service 
$url='http://192.168.0.101/Restler-3rc3-Stable/public/examples/_007_crud/Authors.php';


//READ
if ($method=='GET')
{
    $url=$url.$id;
    $data_array =array();
}
//CREATE
if ($method=='POST')
{
    $data_array =array('id'=>$id);
}
//UPDATE
if ($method=='PUT')
{
    $data_array =array('id'=>$id);
}
//DELETE
if ($method=='DELETE')
{
    $url=$url.$id;
    $data_array =array();
}
$data_array=array('name'=>'ddddd','email'=>'sdfsdf@sdgdsg');
$data = http_build_query($data_array);
$response=do_request($url,$data,NULL,$method,$response_header);

//Output the response and some debug info
echo 'Response Body='. $response;
echo '<hr><pre>Header= : ';
var_dump($response_header);


//Call the the rest service
function do_request($url, $data, $optional_headers = null , $method='GET', &$var)
{

  $params = array('http' => array(
              'method' => $method,
              'content' => $data
            ));
  if ($optional_headers !== null) {
    $params['http']['header'] = $optional_headers;
  }
  $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
  $fp = @fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);

  if (!$fp) {
        $var=$http_response_header;
    throw new Exception("Problem with $url, $php_errormsg");
  }
  $response = @stream_get_contents($fp);
  echo "response".$response;
  if ($response === false) {
        $var=$http_response_header;
    throw new Exception("Problem reading data from $url, $php_errormsg");
  }
    $var=$http_response_header;
    return $response;
}
```

but neither of the both is working . 
I don't know if I'm missing something here . I'm trying to test example 7 "CRUD"
Do I have to include it in index.php of CRUD example ? or Do I have to put index.php code in ur example ? 
where **index.php** is :

```
require_once '../../../vendor/restler.php';
use Luracast\Restler\Restler;

$r = new Restler();
$r->addAPIClass('Authors');
$r->handle();
```

Can anyone help me through this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$data = array("name" => "Another", "email" => "another@email.com");
$data_string = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init('http://restler3.luracast.com/examples/_007_crud/index.php/authors');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo($result);
```

gives you

```
{
  "name": "Another",
  "email": "another@email.com",
  "id": 5
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! Now it's POSTing put when I try to GET it I found the new added user is not added to the Session DB .

Comment: that's because the install function in session.php